# Android AsyncTask On Exit Exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm having problems with my Asynctask. Whenever I exit my app with my BACK button, it just caught an exception. Please take a look at my codes. Please help me to correct it. Thanks.

AndroidFragment.java

```
    public class AndroidFragment extends SherlockListFragment  implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    static final String URL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/86p8y5y2birua9n/test1.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        new loadListView().execute();   
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }

    public class loadListView extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... args) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }




                    return null;
                }   


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {


            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });


            setListAdapter(adapter);
            //pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         if (adapter  != null) {
         setListAdapter(null);
         }
         super.onDestroy();
     }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, this);

        ft.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

LOGCAT :

```
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:85)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.AndroidFragment$loadListView.onPostExecute(AndroidFragment.java:96)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.AndroidFragment$loadListView.onPostExecute(AndroidFragment.java:1)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
10-06 00:17:55.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

New LOGCAT :

```
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:85)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.AppleFragment$loadListView.onPostExecute(AppleFragment.java:97)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.AppleFragment$loadListView.onPostExecute(AppleFragment.java:1)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
10-06 00:49:26.094: E/AndroidRuntime(10780):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you exiting before it finishes?

Comment: nope. Finish loaded all the results then exit. Then it crashed. I got the same problem

Comment: Asynctask should close properly on exit. No matter when

Comment: @DroidBeginner : where is line no SimpleAdapter.java:85 in your code?

Comment: Imran Khan. Its in my onPostExecute. please check

Comment: your "new" logcat doesn't look any different than your old one. you are still getting an error on the new SimpleAdapter call

Comment: I realized too. Does Asynctask have any functions that could close it properly on exit or back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that the fragment isn't attached to the activity when the simple adapter is created. that is the only thing in your new SimpleAdapter call that could return null. move the asynctask request to onViewCreated and see what happens.

UPDATE:
I checked the source code from the SimpleAdapter file. the line throwing the error is trying to create a LayoutInflater from the context you pass in (the activity). that is returning null, so your getactivity() call is returning null.

ANSWER:
Since getActivity() will return null if the fragment is not attached, use the application context to create the SimpleAdapter. You can get the application context from the LayoutInflater passed to onCreateView.

Comment: Do you mean move my asynctask into my onCreateView?

Comment: no. there is a method in the fragment class called onViewCreated, which gets called AFTER onCreateView. i was suggesting moving the creation and execution call to that method just in case. I think that you are going to have issues with the whole tab thing attaching and detaching (although i think you need to be calling ft.commit() at the end of each of those methods)

Comment: So you suggest that I bring my Asynctask into onViewCreated?

Comment: a slightly simpler fix would be to use the application context to create the adapter. that way you avoid the whole problem if your fragment isn't attached to the activity when you create your adapter. you should be able to get the application context from the layoutinflater in oncreateview. just save the return from `inflater.getContext().getApplicationContext()` and use it to create your adapter.

Comment: Thanks toadzky, but I couldnt figure out how it is done. Can you please show me?

Comment: just try the saving the application context in onCreateView. create a member variable: `Context appContext`. In onCreateView: `appContext = inflater.getContext().getApplicationContent();` In onPostExecute: `new SimpleAdapter(appContext, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your list takes to much time to load and parse. Your activity is already destroyed when

```
protected void onPostExecute(String args)
```

is called.

But if activity is already destroyed then you do not need to update UI. The simplest solution will be:

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {

```
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });


            setListAdapter(adapter);
               //pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer works too. But sorry, I'm giving credits to toadzky for his time. Thanks anyway. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Declare Listadapter adapter  at Class Level

```
   @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (adapter  != null) {
            setListAdapter(null);
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }
```